# MySQL - getting previous row data slows down query

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
Id | ApplianceId | Energy
1  | 101         | 0.6
2  | 103         | 1.5
3  | 107         | 1.3
4  | 101         | 1.0
5  | 101         | 1.5
6  | 103         | 2.1
```

What I want to show in query is this (filtered by ApplianceId), [Previous] is the previous [Present] value, [Present] is Energy value, and [Consumption] is Present - Previous:

```
ApplianceId | Previous | Present | Consumption
101         | 0        | 0.6     | 0.6
101         | 0.6      | 1.0     | 0.4
101         | 1.0      | 1.5     | 0.5
```

I already have a working query but it is too slow (cause is when getting the Previous value).

```
SELECT 
    ApplianceId, 
    COALESCE((SELECT MAX(Energy) FROM table WHERE 
    id < t.id AND ApplicationId = '101' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1),0) As Previous,
    Energy AS Present,
    ROUND(MAX(m.wh_total) - (SELECT Previous),2) AS Consumption
FROM
    table t
WHERE ApplicationId = '101'
ORDER BY Id
```

I am querying this on a 100k records and takes about 30 seconds to run. If I remove the part of getting the Previous row, it only takes like 0.4 seconds. Is there any way I can optimize or have another way of getting the previous row value?

Comment: Have you tried to analyze the execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT ApplianceId
      ,COALESCE(LAG(Energy) OVER (ORDER BY ApplianceId),0) PREVIOUS
      ,Energy PRESENT
      ,Energy - COALESCE(LAG(Energy) OVER (ORDER BY ApplianceId),0) FUTURE 
FROM T
WHERE ApplicationId = '101'
GROUP BY ApplianceId, Energy
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MySQL which doesn't have the built in Analytic functions (as of v5.6) that would make this straight forward you have to emulate their behavior with user defined variables in the query, and build it up in stages.

The first step is to emulate the analytic LAG function partitioned by ApplianceID and ordered by ID.  That takes three variables.  One to track the current partition and the one to track the prior energy and a last one to store the next prior energy (that is the current energy).

```
select ID
     , case when @pa != ApplianceID
            then @PriorEnergy := 0.0
            else @PriorEnergy := @ce
       end PriorEnergy
     , @pa := ApplianceID ApplianceID
     , @ce := energy Energy
  from table1
 order by ApplianceID, id;
```

In the above query the case statement handles the partitioning such that when @pa does not match the current ApplianceID then the @PriorEnergy variable is set to 0.0 otherwise the @PriorEnergy variable is set to the current value of @ce, the variable holding the energy value from the previous record.  After the case statement @pa and @ce are updated from the current record to maintain state.  The order by in the above query is important to ensure that the partitioning works correctly.

The next step is to use the above query as part of a larger query to produce the final output:

```
select ApplianceID
     , PriorEnergy Previous
     , Energy Present
     , Energy - PriorEnergy Consumption
from (
select ID
     , case when @pa != ApplianceID
            then @PriorEnergy := 0.0
            else @PriorEnergy := @ce
       end PriorEnergy
     , @pa := ApplianceID ApplianceID
     , @ce := Energy Energy
  from table1
  order by ApplianceID, ID) aq1
order by ApplianceID, id;
```

You can see the results of the above two queryies in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a79f4/34).  Additionally there is a [third query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a79f4/34/2) in the fiddle showing how the consumption can be computed as part of the first analytic query, but do to the constraints on column ordering required to make the analytic processing work, the projection doesn't meet your requirement.